# How to configure properly Base URL/Base Href in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my admin side. my new demo side is at mydomain.com/new/ and admin panel is inside mydomain.com/new/admin/. I am using CKeditor which  as

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.ckeditor').ckeditor( {
filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image',
baseHref : "http://mydomain.com/new", 
baseUrl  : "http://mydomain.com/new",
} );
})
```

```
 <form>

 <textarea name='myeditor' class='ckeditor' id='ckeditor'></textarea>
   </form>
```

Here I have used fileuploader from fckeditor, every thig works fine for uploading, but while displaying uploaded image, ckeditor is not able to load image from uploads folder which is at mydomain.com/new/uploads/.

but when i mode entire site to base directory, i.e. at mydomain.com, and admin site at mydomain.com/admin it is able to display the image inside the editor.

Comment: Did you try adding the trailing slash to `http://mydomain.com/new`? Add `/` to it?